# How to create an Html element again when the user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, html

I did create a Html form tag and Html button tag.

Now I want to create again form tag when the user clicks my button

I think this is possible with JavaScript

If anyone knows please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code. This will add the form once.

```js
let form = document.getElementsByClassName('sample-form')[0]

//make copy of the original form using cloneNode(true). true means JS will copy all the nodes inside of the form element. It's called "deep copy".  
function duplicateForm(){
  return form.cloneNode(true);
}

let addForm = document.getElementById('add-form')


addForm.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.body.append(duplicateForm())
})
```

```html
<form class="sample-form">
  <input placeholder="Your value here"/>
</form>

<button id="add-form">Add New Form</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me Now how can I create a new form in the second or third click

Comment: Let me edit the answer for you.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I have added a  function called duplicateForm and then passed the function on JS append function.